# Get itunes link to whole developer account with no one app submitted

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I know how to get a link to the app before you publish it, but is there a way to get a link to the entire profile, with no apps yet published on AppStore with this account? Link like this one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/google-inc./id281956209

Comment: yes on your itunesconnect page, you can find the link at bottom which includes app-id

Comment: @AmodGokhale Have you read my question? I don't need app id, as i've said - i already know it. I need id/link to whole developer account on AppStore

Comment: to get vendor id - click on Sales & Reports. Click on Reports -> look for developer name and to the right of developer you will get the vendor id..

Comment: @AmodGokhale what do i need that vendor id for?! How could I use it to generate a link to my profile?! It's not the same as developer id on appstore. Here is an id i found in reports 86855411 and here is an actual link to my profile https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/id1043224907

Comment: they have changed itunes portal, i thought i saw my publisher id there... didn't find it anywhere else. I assume when your first app gets published apple creates a publisher id for you? Better send an email to apple to get that details. good question though

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the link to a developer page without any apps. The ID used for the itunes.apple.com link (let's call it developer ID) is not the provider ID you will find in iTunes Connect (just checked with several accounts) and identifies the team you belong on iTunes Connect to.